# Using cookies in 2 distincts websites

Tags: javascript, security, cookies

I have 2 websites and I would like to use the same cookie for both websites. The problem is they are not in the same domain.

How can I do ?

Comment: Forget about asking specific questions about cookies; What functionality are you trying to achieve? There may be a better way to acheive your goal.

Answer (score 1):

You can set two cookies for both domains,  example PHP code:

```
setcookie("TestCookie", "value", $path, "domain1.com");
setcookie("TestCookie", "value", $path, "domain2.com");
```

Link:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can't. Cookies are only sent to the domain they belong to. You most create diferent cookies to  both diferent domains.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with cookies.

You have to save the data of your cookies on your server. You can use a database to do this.